# Question about laurent series and taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis

Represent the function $$f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$$

a)By its McLaurin series, and state where the representation is valid;
b) by its Laurent series in the domain $1<|z|<\infty$

The answers are

a)$-1-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^n (|z|<1)$
b) $1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}$

My question is more about the answers than the process of getting them.
Why can't a) be laurient? or b) be taylor?. I am having a hard seeing the difference between the two

Comment: Taylor series are (infinite) polynomials. So $x^n$ where $n$ is non-negative. Laurent series allow $n$ to be negative (although generally only for finite terms). I'd say b isn't a typical Laurent series. A typical one might look like $$\sum_{n = - 5}^\infty a_n z^n$$ Note there are 5 (a finite number) negative exponents, and infinite positive ones. Note that any laurent series can be written as a Taylor series plus some (finite) negative exponents terms. In this way, a laurent series is more general than a Taylor series.

Comment: so taylor series $\subseteq$  laurent series

Comment: Yeah. I just checked Wikipedia, there was nothing about negative exponents being of finite number, so ignore that (I guess that was just my experience in my complex analysis class).

Comment: I am also taking complex analysis this summer. Which university are you attending?

Comment: I am trying to devour abstract algebra and complex analysis in 1 month XD.

Comment: both fun subjects with some interplay (mobius transformations/linear fractional transformations are interesting both because of analysis and their group structure). Also, taking both can help you determine whether you like more analytic topics or algebraic (or at least start pointing you towards a preference).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44264/discussion-between-daniel-and-mark).

Comment: Taylor's series is particular case of Laurent series